# Are beekeeping/apiculture questions relevant?

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to post questions about beekeeping and apiculture on Gardening and Landscaping?

Answer (score 7):

There is also a [Beekeeping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48193/bees-and-beekeeping) proposal on Area 51. You can support it and spread the word to make it a real site.

Comment: thanks for letting us know!

Comment: this proposal has been restarted @ http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63686/bees-and-beekeeping

Comment: Deleted again it seems

Answer (score 4):

I have a hard time seeing these within our scope. Its not that bees are not important to gardening, its just that animal husbandry in general is not on topic here.

There is an [Animal Husbandry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32167/animal-husbandry) proposal on Area 51. It is still in the early stages but it will be the correct home for these questions whenever it launches.

Comment: I would concur with waxeagle.  Beekeeping is relevant in gardening insofar as they help in pollination, but otherwise...

Comment: The Animal Husbandry proposal has since been deleted, but there two possible replacements: [Farming and Agriculture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55008/farming-and-agriculture), and [Agriculture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50444/agriculture).

Comment: Beekeeping proposal @ http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63686/bees-and-beekeeping